# XGBoost model in Spark --> Missing value treatment

Tags: missing-data, boosting, spark-mllib

Unlike python, where missing value is handled internally by the XGBoost algorithm, While building XGBoost model in SPARK, the missing values are implicitly converted to 0.0(float?!). Is this okay ? There are real values that may be 0.0.How can we be sure this doesn't interfere with the model prediction abilities ?

Comment: Actually this is *ON* topic because it does not ask how to do this in Spark but rather if what happens in the Spark implementation is harmful.